# Is this a correct algorithm to calculate interior product?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields

I have looked at the formula for this for several sources but the notation is very confusing. Looking at a few limited examples leads me to believe that the method may be the perscription:

Let a manifold M have local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)\varepsilon \mathbb{R}^n$

For vector field $v \varepsilon TM \text{ defined } v = v^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ and differential form $\omega \varepsilon \Lambda^q$ (with a confusing notation for general formula)

the interior product $\iota_v(\omega) \varepsilon \Lambda^{(q-1)}$ is calculated by:

For each element $v^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ of the vector field, go through the expression for $\omega$ and, for any term containing $dx^a$:

1. Eliminate the $dx^a$ in the term
2. Multiply the term by $v^a$
3. Multiply the term by -1 to the power of the number of times you had to swap dx's to get $dx_a$ to the front.
4. Add this transformed term to your $\iota_v(\omega)$ evaluation

This is what I've pieced together from a few examples but I've only seen a few so I'm not very confident in this. Could someone please explain how to properly do this in a algorithmic way? (An example would be amazing but no worries if not)

Comment: There is a formula for this,  see Lee smooth manifolds for a derivation. It is derived in a straightforward way from the algebraic definition of $i_v(\omega)$, which says that $i_v(\omega)(X_1, \dots, X_{q - 1}) = \omega(v, X_1, \dots, X_{q - 1})$ for vectors $X_1, \dots, X_{q - 1}$.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence following the list. Can you explain and give an example? Other than that, your algorithm seems fine to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, that was just a misunderstanding of the evaluation of an example which led me to believe this. I've resolved this going back over it though so I'll remove that line from the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are evaluating your $q$-differential form $\omega$ on $(v,z_1,\dots z_{q-1})$ where the $z_i$ are free, resulting in a $(q-1)$-differential form acting on $(z_1,z_2,\dots z_{q-1})$. Here is an example.

Suppose you have a 2-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$
\omega=a(x)dx_1\wedge dx_2+b(x)dx_2\wedge dx_3+c(x)dx_1\wedge dx_3
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, and a vector field $v=(v_1(x),v_2(x),v_3(x))$.

Then, given a generic vector field $z(x)$ (I will omit the argument $x$ for simplicity)
$$
i_v(\omega)(z)=\omega(v,z)=a(v_1z_2-v_2z_1)+b(v_2z_3-v_3z_2)+c(v_1z_3-v_3z_1)
$$
and, rearranging,
$$
i_v(\omega)(z)=(-av_2-cv_3)z_1+(av_1-bv_3)z_2+(bv_2+cv_1)z_3,
$$

So, the resulting $1$-form is
$$
i_v(\omega)=(-av_2-cv_3)dx_1+(av_1-bv_3)dx_2+(bv_2+cv_1)dx_3
$$

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm still a bit confused about the meaning of some lines though.        
My understanding of your working is $\iota_v(\omega) = v(a\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1})+v(b\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2})+v(c\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3})$ giving you the line: $\iota_v(\omega) = a(v_1dx_2-v_2dx_1)+b(v_2dx_3-v_3dx_2)+c(v_1dx_3-v_3dx_1)$ which rearranges to  $\iota_v(\omega)=(−av_2−cv_3)dx_1+(av_1−bv_3)dx_2+(bv_2+cv_1)dx_3$. Is this a correct way to evaluate this? I just want a simple methodology to calculate this. Thanks again!

Comment: I don’t understand your first line in this comment.

Comment: Sorry, messed up the notation. I meant to have $v(a dx_i)$ as in pair all the terms of v with the $a dx_i$ term